# Как создать сканворд в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Скажите подробно, заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вам понадобится таблица, в которую вы будете вписывать вопросы и ответы.
Если вы хотите сделать программу, которая будет выдавать пользователю различные сканворды, то у вас есть два пути.

1. Вы будете заранее составлять сканворды и где-то хранить таблицы, которые потом будут выдаваться пользователю для решения.
2. Сканворд будет генерироваться программой. Тут круче. Вам надо будет сделать словарь и алгоритм, который будет перебирать слова и создавать сетку.

Для общего развития: [сканворд](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%EA%E0%ED%E2%EE%F0%E4).